# Why won't my RAID controller boot on 1x PCIe?

Tags: raid, pci-express

- I have an Adaptec 1x SAS (4x PCIe) 3405 that works on 1x PCI.
- I have an Adaptec 2x SAS (8x PCIe) 5805 that "boots" but hangs the OS on boot or the device stops working on boot and doesn't show in the OS.
- I have a slightly newer Adaptec 2x SAS (8x PCIe) 6805 that won't even start the boot sequence unless I plug it into my 16x slot.

It was my belief that any PCIe device could work off 1x PCIe lane but can easily max it out if it is designed to use more than one lane like a video card.

I'm trying to get a 2x SAS card to work on a 1x PCIe.

What do I need to look for if I'm going to find another card that will work?